# Shortcut to turn on Resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, shortcut

Usually I start VS2008 without Resharper because it makes VS startup way too slow and I just need to fix a bug.  But sometimes, I do want to turn on Resharper.

Is there a way to setup a keyboard shortcut that enables Resharper?

Comment: Not really. You can disable code analysis using Ctrl-Alt-8 but that's not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close out this question, I did eventually find an [answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5268946#5268946) with R# 5.x.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but Tools/Add-in Manager will let you dynamically load an add-in. You could probably use Tools/Macros to record yourself using the Add-in Manager and then assign a saved macro to a keystroke.

Alternately, see "How to: Run Add-ins on the Command Line" in the help; you could then create two shortcuts for VS with and without R#.

If you have sufficient memory it's simpler just to leave VS running all day. I wouldn't even fix a bug without ReSharper... :)